# Como fazer para o código olhar um if apenas depois de ter mudado a prop de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, front-end, react

Eu tenho um formulário que quando clico em enviar deixa vermelho o campo que estiver vazio. Ele faz diferentes validações em cada um dos campos. Apenas quando todos os campos estiverem com borda cinza ele envia os dados via post e desabilita a mensagem de erro.

**O problema**

Dentro do método handleClick ele faz as alterações de estado caso o campo esteja corretamente preenchido e no fim faz uma verificação final em todos os campos. Se tudo estiver cinza envia os dados, se não mantém o erro. Mas na primeira vez que clico envia mesmo estando errado, e apenas na segunda vez que clico descobre o erro. Isso acontece porque está entrando no meu if antes de fazer as alterações nos campos usando `setState`. Tentei usar setTimeout mas não funcionou e me disseram não ser uma boa prática. Como proceder para o if ficar async e só ser ativado quando os states estiverem atualizados?

```
if ((valueColor && nameColor && lastNameColor && emailColor 
      && cardColor && cvvColor && cpfColor
      && dateColor && periodicityColor) === 'grey') {
      console.log('dentro'); this.errorMessage.message = 'none'; //this.handleSubmit();
    } else {
      console.log('fora'); this.errorMessage.message = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: Agir com base no estilo e não no resultado da validação é má pratica, e acaba por se tornar evidente no seu caso. De que forma estão os campos a ser validados? Coloque também o código que valida na pergunta

Comment: Essa foi uma boa dica rapaz, vou analisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIÇÃO


Voce tinha pedido async daí eu fiquei confundido.

Nessa edição eu removi o component com metodo assincrono que não tinha a ver com a pergunta.

---

### Agora vamos para o que interessa

```
//Cabeçalho dos exemplos abaixo
import React from "react";

function verifyEmail(email){
    let phone = document.querySelector(".phone");
    ...whatever
}
function verifyPhone()
{
    let email = document.querySelector(".email");
    ...whatever
}
```

**Sem usar async e sem usar this.state**

```
class Register extends React.Component
{
    componentWillMount() {
        this.fields = {email:false,phone:false};
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        this.fields.email = verifyEmail();
        this.fields.phone = verifyPhone();

        if (this.fields.email === true && this.fields.phone === true) {
            ...Do something
        } else {
            ...Error
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input onClick={this.handleClick}>
        );
    }
}
```

**Usando callbacks na função** `this.setState([Object, Callback])`

```
class Register extends React.Component
{
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            email: false,
            phone: false //false é que não está correto
        });
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        let email = verifyEmail();
        let phone = verifyPhone();

        this.setState({
            email: email, //resultado da função verifyEmail()
            phone: phone //resultado da função verifyPhone()
        }, () => {
            if (this.state.email === true && this.state.phone === true) {
                ...Do something
            } else {
                ...Error
            }
        });

        //NOTE: setState acima tem um callback como segundo parametro,
        //quando os estados atualizarem, esse calback é chamado
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input onClick={this.handleClick}>
        );
    }
}
```